# Let G be the group of rigid motions of a cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Show that $|G| = 24$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $G$ be the group of rigid motions of a cube. We aim to prove that the order of $G$, denoted as $|G|$, is 24.

Assume each vertex of the cube is labeled as $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_8$. Consider sending vertex $v_1$ to position $p_k$. Then, vertex $v_2$ can only be relocated to any of the three positions adjacent to $p_k$. Once the positions for $v_1$ and $v_2$ have been determined, the positions for all other vertices are uniquely determined, as rigid motions preserve distances and angles. This arrangement results in a total of $8 \cdot 3 = 24$ possibilities, as we have $8$ choices of where to send $v_1$ and $3$ choices for $v_2$.

Is this proof sufficiently rigorous? Any tips?

Comment: This is fine, except for the fact that someone might want more detailed justification for why the positions of the remaining vertices are uniquely determined. If you know the orbit/stabilizer theorem, I would use that directly.